# Isolate scope value is replaced only if it exists - AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Template**:

```
<ui-print text="Print" panel="#paper1" 
          wait-for-data="adc.waitForData" 
          callfront-fn="adc.someFunction()"></ui-print>

<ui-print text="Print" panel="#paper2"></ui-print>
```

**Directive**:

```
scope: {
    text: '@',
    panel: '@',
    callfrontFn: '&',
    waitForData: '='
},

link: function($scope) {
    var invokePrint = function(panel) {
        $window.print();
        $scope.waitForData = true;
    }

    $scope.printPanel = function(panel) {
        if (!$scope.waitForData) {
            invokePrint(panel);
        } else {
            $scope.callfrontFn();
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch('waitForData', function(n) {
        if (n === false) {
            invokePrint($scope.panel);
        }
    });
}
```

Hi guys, I am trying to understand how the **isolate** **scope** works here. If you look at the above code there are 2 element directives. 1 has **waitForData** and the other doesn't.

In the 2nd **directive**, when I `invokePrint()` and there is `$scope.waitForData=true`, which is not triggering the `$watch`. But in the 1st **directive** it does.

Is it like when the **isolate scope** is not passed its value cannot be replaced in the directive? I do not understand why it is behaving like that.

I just wanted to know why the watch is not triggered in the 2nd directive when `$scope.waitForData = true`, but triggered in the 1st directive.

*Sorry I could not post the entire code due to security reasons. But this is the code that needs to be debugged.*

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Comment: As you can see `callfrontFn: '&'`, and `waitForData: '='` in your isolated scope which are not available in your second directive template. so it won't work.

Comment: so both scopes are pointing to corresponding attribute from template. I think you need to go through `directives` in detail. That will help you for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
waitForData: '='
```

Means that you require the variable waitForData. If you don't supply one then it wont break straight away but it will break as soon as you try to set the value. Open up your console and you will see the error messages. 
if you wish the value to be optional then append a question mark like so:

```
waitForData: '=?'
```

Now if you change the waitForData variable in the second directive it will trigger the watch. You should append a question mark to all of the optional variables or teh directive will break as soon as you try and use them.